# Texture Scaling

Tags: c++, scaling, directx-9, texture2d

Using Direct-X9, how can I scale my texture to the exact size it is in the file?

I view my texture in MSPaint and it is 261 x 210 in size. It displays fine in MSPaint.
However, when I draw my texture, it draws far larger than normal. It's stretched for some reason even though I set the scaling to 0f.

My code is as follows:

```
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
#define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <d3dx9tex.h>

IDirect3D9* d3d = nullptr;
IDirect3DDevice9* device = nullptr;
IDirect3DTexture9* Texture = nullptr;
ID3DXSprite* Sprite = nullptr;

const int Width = 800;
const int Height = 600;

void init(HWND hwnd, IDirect3D9* &d3d, IDirect3DDevice9* &device, int Width, int Height);
void render(IDirect3DDevice9* device);
void cleanup(IDirect3D9* &d3d, IDirect3DDevice9* &device);
void LoadTexture(const char* FilePath, IDirect3DTexture9* &Texture, ID3DXSprite* &Sprite);
void LoadTexture(unsigned char* buffer, int width, int height, IDirect3DTexture9* &Texture, ID3DXSprite* &Sprite);


LRESULT __stdcall WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg = {0};

    WNDCLASSEX wc =
    {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW | CS_OWNDC,
        WindowProcedure, 0, 0, hInstance, nullptr, nullptr, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1),
        nullptr, _T("DXClass"), nullptr
    };

    if(RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(_T("DXClass"), _T("DirectX Window"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, Width, Height, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
        ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        init(hwnd, d3d, device, Width, Height);
        LoadTexture("C:/Users/School/Desktop/Test.bmp", Texture, Sprite);

        while(true)
        {
            while(PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }

            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            render(device);
        }

        cleanup(d3d, device);
        return msg.wParam;
    }
    return 0;
}


void init(HWND hwnd, IDirect3D9* &d3d, IDirect3DDevice9* &device, int Width, int Height)
{
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS parameters = {0};
    ZeroMemory(&parameters, sizeof(parameters));
    parameters.Windowed = true;
    parameters.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    parameters.hDeviceWindow = hwnd;
    parameters.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    parameters.BackBufferWidth = Width;
    parameters.BackBufferHeight = Height;
    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hwnd, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &parameters, &device);
}

void render(IDirect3DDevice9* device)
{
    device->Clear(0, nullptr, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 40, 100), 1.0f, 0);
    device->BeginScene();

    if (Sprite && Texture)
    {
        D3DXMATRIX world = {0}, rotation = {0}, scale = {0}, translation = {0};
        D3DXMatrixIdentity(&world);

        D3DXMatrixScaling(&scale, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        D3DXMatrixRotationYawPitchRoll(&rotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        world = rotation * scale * translation;

        Sprite->SetTransform(&world);
        D3DXVECTOR3 Position = D3DXVECTOR3(0, 0, 0);

        Sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
        Sprite->Draw(Texture, nullptr, nullptr, &Position, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        Sprite->End();
    }

    device->EndScene();
    device->Present(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
}

void cleanup(IDirect3D9* &d3d, IDirect3DDevice9* &device)
{
    if (Sprite) Sprite->Release();
    if (Texture) Texture->Release();
    if (device) device->Release();
    if (d3d) d3d->Release();
}

void LoadTexture(const char* FilePath, IDirect3DTexture9* &Texture, ID3DXSprite* &Sprite)
{
    D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(device, FilePath, &Texture);
    D3DXCreateSprite(device, &Sprite);
}

void LoadTexture(unsigned char* buffer, int width, int height, IDirect3DTexture9* &Texture, ID3DXSprite* &Sprite)
{
    device->CreateTexture(width, height, 1, 0, D3DFMT_X8B8G8R8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &Texture, 0);
    D3DXCreateSprite(device, &Sprite);

    D3DLOCKED_RECT rect;
    Texture->LockRect(0, &rect, nullptr, D3DLOCK_DISCARD);
    unsigned char* dest = static_cast<unsigned char*>(rect.pBits);
    memcpy(dest, buffer, width * height * 4);
    Texture->UnlockRect(0);
}
```

Any ideas? Also, is there a better way to draw my texture? For example, maybe without the sprite? I am very new to Direct-X.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, texture surfaces are usually required to be power of 2 in dimensions: e.g. 64, 512, etc. 
   Although different hardware implements rasterization differently, addressing individual pixels of a texture will require a great deal of multiplication. For example, to address a texel in an image, you could use this code:

```
texel = PixelDataArray[y * texture_width + x];
```

however, if 'texture_width' is a power of two, say 256, then then would do the same job:

```
int texture_width_shift_by = 8;
texel = PixelDataArray[y << texture_width_shift_by + x];
```

The advantage being that implementing a shift in hardware takes a lot less silicon can operate a lot faster than a multiply. When you're doing millions of such operations every frame using parallel hardware, the gains can be significant.

Anyway, the upshot is that you must save that image with power of two dimensions and then, if you want to use a clipped region within that surface, do this using UV coordinates.